# Python Parser to resolve IP address from hostnames in text file

Tags: python, sockets, dns

I'm attempting to resolve the hostnames I have in a text file to IPs using sockets.

**file.txt**:

```
google.com
yahoo.com
iliketurtles.com

import socket
with open("file.txt", "r") as ins:
  for line in ins:
    print  socket.gethostbyname(line.strip())
```

I'm getting the following gaierror:

> print  socket.gethostbyname(line.strip()) socket.gaierror: [Errno 8]
>   nodename nor servname provided, or not known

What do I need to do differently to resolve the hostname on each line of the file and print to standard output?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Or you sure that `line.strip()` is not empty? Do you have some trailing end of line characters in your file? Also you should look at `socket.getaddrinfo()` instead of `socket.gethostbyname()` for all the reasons explained in the `socket` documentation.

Answer (score 1):

This code works for me. Sounds like it's a network issue. Check your internet connection - try to ping this servers and check that your DNS server works correctly.

Comment: I can ping all the hosts in my list and run dig command on them individually. I'm on OSX. What OS are you testing from? Also I'm on Python 2.7

Comment: I also use OSX. I tested on both versions.